# How to move a lambda capturing a non-copyable object to a std::function?

Tags: c++

In my C++ code, I've defined a class test_t that disables copy construction and copy assignment operators, allowing only move operations. Then, I created a lambda expression f capturing an object a of type test_t and moved it into the lambda. Now, I want to move this lambda expression f to a std::function<void()> object to pass it to the func_a function.

However, I encountered a compilation error indicating that I cannot move f to std::function<void()>. How can I resolve this issue?

c++20

```cpp
#include <functional>

class test_t {
public:
    test_t() = default;
    ~test_t() = default;

    test_t(const test_t&) = delete;
    auto operator=(const test_t&) = delete;

    test_t(test_t&& other) noexcept = default;
    auto operator=(test_t&& other) noexcept -> test_t & = default;
};

auto func_a(std::function<void()> f) {
}

int main() {
    test_t a;
    auto f = [b = std::move(a)]() mutable {};
    auto f2 = std::move(f); // ok
    //func_a(std::move(f)); // error
}
```

Comment: C++23 `std::move_only_function` is [what you need](https://godbolt.org/z/j4zjEqcf6).

Comment: Question stated C++20

Comment: @possum and the answer is `std::function` is incompatible with move-only functors